# String was not recognised as a valid DateTime when parsing

Tags: c#, discord.net

So I have some code that will write the current DateTime to a txt file and then post some embeds, if the txt file doesn't exist. If it does, then it will read the file, check if the date in the file was over 1 minute ago, if it was it should send  the same embed as the one that creates the file, if it hasn't been 1 minute then it will send an embed telling you to wait.

For some reason, the creating and sending aspect works fine, but if I run the command again, when it tries to convert the string to a DateTime it fails, saying "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.". I have checked multiple websites and the datetime format I am using is correct. Any ideas?

```
string FilePath22 = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/servers/" + Context.Guild.Id + ".txt";
string FilePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/descriptions/" + Context.Guild.Id + ".txt";
string FilePath2 = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/invites/" + Context.Guild.Id + ".txt";
var chnl = Context.Client.GetChannel(511281184760791056) as ITextChannel;
string invitelink = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath2);
string desclink = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
var builder2 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .WithColor(Color.Orange)
        .WithAuthor(Context.Guild.Name)
        .WithThumbnailUrl(Context.Guild.IconUrl)
        .WithUrl(invitelink)
        .AddField("Information", "**Owner:** " + Context.Guild.Owner + Environment.NewLine +
        "**Description:** " + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + desclink + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "**Invite:** " + invitelink)
        .AddField("Other Info", "**Members:** " + Context.Guild.MemberCount + Environment.NewLine + "**Emotes:** " + Context.Guild.Emotes.Count + Environment.NewLine + "**Roles:** " + Context.Guild.Roles.Count + Environment.NewLine + "**Created At:** " + Context.Guild.CreatedAt.Date);
        var embed2 = builder2.Build();
        await chnl.SendMessageAsync(embed: embed2);
        var builder44 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .WithColor(Color.Orange)
        .WithTitle("Server Bumped!");
var embed44 = builder44.Build();

if (!File.Exists(FilePath22))
{
    await ReplyAsync(embed: embed44);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(FilePath22, DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    return;
}

string readit = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath22);
Console.WriteLine(readit);
var converted = DateTime.Parse(readit); //problem
Console.WriteLine(converted);
if (HoursPassed(converted))
{
    await ReplyAsync(embed: embed44);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(FilePath22, DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    return;
}

var builder10 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .WithColor(Color.Orange)
        .WithTitle("You must wait 24 hours before bumping your server! Try again later.");
var embed10 = builder10.Build();
await ReplyAsync(embed: embed10);
```

Comment: What does the `DateTime` string you are having difficulty parsing actually look like?

Comment: When you print out the line to the console what does the string look like the second time? I'm guessing there is an extra character there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact()` or `DateTime.TryParseExact()`, e.g.

```
DateTime converted;
DateTime.TryParseExact(readit, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out converted);
```

With `DateTime.Parse()` it could be problem if the server default format is different from yours.